# Log keeps displaying the same error message at a rate of ~5 per second

Tags: macos, error, console

For some reason, I keep getting this message 5 times on the console every second (approximately):

```
mdworker[56948]: (Warning) Import: Bad path:
```

What does this mean? What are the symptoms of this?

If it helps, the following processes I am running: 
Chrome, Skype, Photoshop, Xcode, Calculator, Applescript Editor, Terminal, Disk Utility

And I also have a no-ip DUC Daemon running

UPDATE: It stopped, and threw some logs similar to this:

```
11.05.15 21:39:51,000 kernel[0]: [0x4af4807000, 0x1004000]
```

and an extremely long log with kernel: at the start: http://pastebin.com/Y5h2MgEu

UPDATE: It started again, so I restarted and now the mdworker shows a message 14-17 times a second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Exclude from Spotlight

Others reporting this problem suggest external storage may be the cause; a USB stick, network drive, or NAS.

If you have any external storage connected to your Mac, try adding it to the **Spotlight Privacy** list:

- System Preferences > Spotlight > Privacy > + Button

`mdworker` is a helper process for Spotlight on OS X.

#### Sources

[Mdworker : (Warning) Import : Bad path:](http://www.tonymacx86.com/mavericks-laptop-support/138543-mdworker-warning-import-bad-path.html) wrote:

> The problem is MacOS/Spotlight indexing cannot handle partition in NTFS/FAT32 format, which is windows stuff.

[mdworker: (warning) import bad path continuously.  What does it mean?](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5506695?start=0&tstart=0) wrote:

> This happened to me too with a fat partition that I have mounted which I share with my other OSs.

Stephen Foskett shared his experience with this bug in [Mac OS X Bug: ExFAT Hangs Spotlight and Time Machine](http://blog.fosketts.net/2013/12/04/mac-os-bug-exfat-hangs-spotlight-time-machine/):

> I’ve had terrible issues with Mac OS X never completing Spotlight indexing and Time Machine backups. I was pulling out my hair until I decided to check the console log. That’s when I saw this: Thousands of mdworker errors, with a dozen appearing every second.

Comment: Yes! That was it. It's late now, but I did forget to mention that it said KINGSTON indexing forever. And it was coincidentally also a FAT partition